# Connecting to Aurora AWS Serverless

Tags: amazon-aurora

I’ve now tried to create a serverless Aurora (MySQL compatible) database and connect to it for two days, and I just can’t seem to get it to work. Supposedly I should have been able to get it up and running in five minutes.

In any case, I created am Aurora Serverless database in the US East (N. Virginia) region (us-east-1), and have been able to connect to it with the AWS Query Editor. I also have an EC2 server in the same region, and have given the Aurora database the same security group (under RDS > Security Group), and in the security group I have opened for MYSQL/Aurora (TCP, 3306) from all sources. When I click the modify button on the database, there is also another (VPC) Security Group listed (rds-launch-wizard-4), which was created automatically. This one I also located under my EC2 dashboard and gave access to all ports from all sources (inbound), and to all ports (outbound). And there is a networking VPC & subnet group, which I don’t know what to do with, if anything.

I try to connect to the database, using this command line command: 
mysql -h hest2.cluster-xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root –p

It generates an error “ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on” on both my EC2 instance, my local computer and on other online servers.

Answer (score 3):

From the EC2 instance, try doing a telnet on the DB port to test if all your security group settings are applied correctly.

> telnet hest2.cluster-xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306

If the connection does go through, then the issue is with your client code. Cross check that you have wired the right endpoint in your code.

If the telnet connection does not group (I'm guessing that it would not), then it is guaranteed that your security group settings are not set correctly. In order to debug this further, we would need more details on:

1. The list of vpc security groups associated with your cluster.
2. The details of each of these vpc security groups (You've mentioned that
   you've opened up everything, but I'd like to see the exact rules in
   place)

As for laptop and other servers - If they are outside the VPC, then it would not work. Aurora Serverless is accessible only from within the VPC as of now.